# Grouped Barplot with ggplot and special order of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to make a **Barplot** with R (I usually use ggplot2), but I don´t know what to do in this special case... Here is a reproducable data example:

```
NGS <- c("NGS01", "NGS02", "NGS03", "NGS01", "NGS02", "NGS03")
R56 <- c(0.04, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.045)
R57 <- c(0.08, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07, 0.03, 0.05)
a <- c("two", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three")
data <- data.frame(NGS, R56, R57, a)
```

My data frame is much larger, but has this structure..

What I need:
A Barplot from R56 (and later an extra one from R57).

But the **bars should have this order**:

NGS01 from a=two, then NGS 01 from a=three; then NGS 02 from a = two, then NGS 02 from a= three... and so on.

So I need the bars sorted after NGS and a (the time variable). What I want to show with this plot are differences/ equality in the values from R56 for different persons (NGS variable) at different measurements (a variable)...

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me how to display this! I don´t know how to make this grouping with ggplot2... Thanks for every tip!

Comment: If your question is about ordering x-axis there are multiple questions like that here on SO. Can you post what have you tried and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you needed?

```
ggplot(data, aes(NGS, R56, fill=a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]